# Which CPU is being emulated by Qemu by default?

Tags: qemu

I'm currently running a VM without selecting a CPU type. How can I know which one is being emulated? Is there a way to ask this to the Qemu monitor?

Host machine is Windows 10 and guest is Plan 9. Not using KVM.

Comment: Which architecture setup is the system using ?